# How to split file on Windows 2003 using MS supported tool

Tags: windows, compression

Is it possible to split a large file into smaller files on Windows 2003 using a tool provided/supported/sanctioned by Microsoft?

I see that there are a lot of freeware tools (various zip tools) for this task, but I need to move files off of a production server, thus would like to avoid tools I don't know if I can trust. I would much prefer some tool included in the Windows Server 2003 Resource Kit Tools or something along those lines. Does such a tool exist?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know of an MS tool that will do it, unless one of the Visual Studio packaging tools will (I never have to use them).

Why don't you trust 7zip or Winzip or WinRAR?  I seriously doubt that anything MS provides would eclipse them and they are very widely used.

Answer (score 3):

How about MS Cabinet files?  MS provides a [dev kit](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/310618).  You can specify a disk size to split the archive up at with makecab.  Here's [some documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd583149%28office.11%29.aspx) on how to do it.

I personally use winrar, but its not MS sanctioned.